# TweenJS javascript

Tags: javascript, createjs, tween, tween.js

My first Stackoverflow question. The tween seems to run because it calls the brute function at the end. However, there's no tween happening.

```js
window.onload=init();
function init() {
    testImg = document.getElementById("testImg");
    createjs.Tween.get(testImg).wait(2000).to({alpha: 1}, 600).call(brute);
}
function brute() {
    // why this function get called if there's no visible tween?
    console.log("testImg alpha is " + testImg.alpha)
    testImg.style.opacity=1;
}
```

```css
#testImg {
    opacity: .3;
    background: url("http://oyos.org/oyosbtn_466x621.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="testImg">
        here is the div
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

TweenJS isn't really optimized to tween styles on HTML elements, since it was developed to tween properties directly on objects. There is a [CSS plugin](https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/blob/master/src/tweenjs/plugins/CSSPlugin.js) that can help, particularly when dealing with properties that have suffixes (like "px" on width/height, etc)

However, it can definitely be done. There are a few issues with your code:

1. As you mentioned in your comment above, you have to target the "opacity" instead. The `alpha` property is what EaselJS DisplayObjects use.
2. You have to target the `testImg.style` instead, since the opacity lives on that element, and not on the `testImg` directly. Setting opacity/alpha on the #testImg will do nothing
3. Unfortunately, TweenJS doesn't know how to read CSS properties set on elements using CSS classes or selectors. The `getComputedStyle` is *very* expensive to look up, and is required to determine what the current style of the element is.

You can totally make your demo work, but you have to consider these things. Here is an updated snippet (from this [pen](http://codepen.io/lannymcnie/pen/YZaqMO)):

```
createjs.Tween.get(testImg.style)     // Target the style
  .to({opacity:0.3})                  // Set the property initially
  .wait(2000)
  .to({opacity: 1}, 600)
  .call(brute); // Tween the opacity instead
```

You could also use the `change` event to update the opacity yourself:

```
createjs.Tween.get(testImg)
  .set({alpha:0}) // Still requires an initial set
  .wait(2000)
  .to({alpha:1})
  .call(brute)
  .on("change", function(event) {
    // Every time the tween is updated, set the opacity
    testImg.style.opacity = testImg.alpha;
  });
```

Note that the CSS plugin I mentioned above *can* handle the computedStyle lookup now (a fairly recent addition).

Hope that sheds some light on the behaviour.
Cheers,